# WSO2 IS - Blazor SPA 'Invalid request client_id not found in request as parameter.'

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, wso2, blazor-webassembly, wso2-identity-server

When trying to login as the default `admin` user against WSO2 Identity Server from my Blazor SPA I get the following error:

[image: client_id not found in request as parameter]

but the authentication succeeds and the user is logged in.

The settings in my Service Provider are the following:

[image: Service Provider settings]

and the code for connecting to WSO2 IS:

`Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>{
{
  builder.Configuration.Bind("Local", options.ProviderOptions);
});
```

`Appsettings.json`

```
{
  "Local": {
    "Authority": "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/oidcdiscovery",
    "ClientId": "lUf05M1d3IRvpdOkZgLSt9TRZX8a",
    "ResponseType": "code",
    "DefaultScopes": [],
    "RedirectUri": "authentication/login-callback",
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "signedOut"
  }
}
```

When the option "Allow authentication without the client secret" in the Service Provider is unchecked, authentication results in an error and the user cannot log in.

[image: POST request 401]

Response:

```
error_description: Unsupported Client Authentication Method!
error: invalid_client
```

Is this the expected behaviour?

`OAuth Version: OAuth-2.0`

Allowed grant types:

`Code,Implicit,Password,Client Credential, Refresh Token`

Comment: What is the error you get in wso2carbon.log file located in <IS-HOME>/repository/logs

Comment: Taken from wso2carbon.log, https://pastebin.com/7NkYwGJX

Comment: The error in the carbon log is for a different request related to OIDC session management. The error which you have got should not be returned if "Allow authentication without client secret" is checked. Can you check whether you are referring to the correct service provider?

Comment: @Sajith When the aforementioned option is **checked** I am able to log in as expected but when it's **unchecked** I am getting the reported error. I am trying to figure out how to log in from a SPA with that option enabled.

Comment: @Sajith https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/5097

Answer (score 0):

The error `client_id not found in request as parameter.` is logged for a request related to OIDC session management. It occures when the OIDC session management iframe is loaded without the client id query paramter.

The 401 error for the token request is expected if "Allow authentication without client secret" is unchecked and you are not passing the client secret in the token request.